# Magento Tupertine authentication error

Tags: magento, module

I have install a module in my magento(1.9.1) store to cache pages with varnish called tupertine, but i got some issues with it.

After the installation I entered in the file: /etc/varnish/secret and copied the secret key, so I went back to the backend and pasted this key, however to save the system shows me the following message:

```
Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:6082: Got unexpected response code from Varnish: 107 ftfavpxpdqciyfzwuwtddrefouwffsdl Authentication required.
```

Reading the module documentation: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Configuration checked that the key contains a line break, then it is suggested to put a /n at the end of the key in backend

When trying to put /n the key in the backend system displays the following message:

```
Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:6082: Varnish data to write over length limit by 122 characters

Varnish esi_syntax param is not set correctly, please see these instructions to fix this warning.
```

the key was :

```
b6736327-be5e-4b52-a05a-875ea9271424
```

and looked like this:

```
b6736327-be5e-4b52-a05a-875ea9271424\n
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
edit file varnish

```
sudo nano /etc/default/varnish
```

set this for "DAEMON_OPTS"

```
DAEMON_OPTS=" 
             -p cli_buffer=16384 \
             -a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \

             -s malloc,256m"
```